# How can I see where the error is in this Reactjs debug image

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I keep getting this screen and it always stop at Main.Chunk.js like the image show

I'm new to Reactjc and cannot makeout if this happens because of the

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

That also is showed on the image or if there is some other reason for this.

Any suggestions help would be cool!
[image]

**UPDATE**

When I remove the 4 script line that are high-lighted in this picture the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

goes away!

[image]

Then instead execution hangs here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1812) solution.

Basically, you could try to change this:

```
app.use(express.static('client/build'));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(require('path')
        .resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
})
```

to:

```
const root = require('path').join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')
app.use(express.static(root));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
})
```

Comment: That did not change anything

Comment: Ciao @ExocetKid in discussion I posted this is the most quoted solution. But not the only one. Have you tried also the other suggestions?

Comment: I used create-react-app I dont I have "PublicPath" webpack settings. I'm new to this not sure

Comment: @ExocetKid Ok I didn't know that you used create-react-app. I updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: I search for `app.use` and it does not exist in my [project](http://greta.portplays.com/)

Comment: please advice I just learn react coming from Android and Java

Comment: I updated my question with some progress or not dunno what you think